# Expression contains undeclared variables using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, geojson, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using gee to perform overlay analysis on two periods of raster data. The original image resolution is 10m and the size is 4.6G, but the superimposed output (lcall) has a memory size of up to 40G.

Through the search, it is found that some people use cluster method to reduce the dimension of data, so as to reduce the volume of data. However, when I use this method, I always get the error

> "Image.parseExpression: Expression contains undeclared variables:
> [cluster]."

Here is my original code:

```
// Apply DBSCAN algorithm to cluster the pixels
var clustering = lcall.reduceNeighborhood({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  kernel: ee.Kernel.square({radius: 1}),
  skipMasked: false
});
// Rename the resulting cluster image
var cluster = clustering.rename('cluster');
// Convert the resulting cluster image to a binary raster
var clustersBinary = cluster.expression('cluster > 0 ? 1 : 0');
// Convert the binary raster to a FeatureCollection
var clusters = clustersBinary.reduceToVectors({
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  crs: lcall.projection(),
  scale: lcall.projection().nominalScale(),
  geometry: lcall.geometry(),
  eightConnected: false,
  labelProperty: 'labels',
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
print(clusters);
// Visualize the clusters
Map.addLayer(clusters, {'':'FF0000'}, 'clusters');
```

Complete code：
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmcm%2Fcode%3Aintersect

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Get Link` button in the EE Code Editor when linking to your script. I couldn't run your code, but the specific error you get comes from this:

```
var clustersBinary = cluster.expression('cluster > 0 ? 1 : 0');
```

You have a second `map` argument in `expression()` where you provide the variables used in the expression:

```
var clustersBinary = cluster.expression('cluster > 0 ? 1 : 0', {cluster: cluster})
```

Alternatively, you can use the `b()` syntax:

```
var clustersBinary = cluster.expression("b('cluster') > 0 ? 1 : 0")
```

Personally, for this case, I'd simply do this:

```
var clustersBinary = cluster.gt(0)
```